# Initialize pointer inside function. How it works?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code and it works:

```
void InitPointer(int** pp)
{
    *pp = new int{ 10 };
}

int* p{ nullptr };
InitPointer(&p);
```

Can you help me figure out how it works? The raw pointer **int* p** points nowhere. How can I write to nowhere?
For example, this code throws rte:

```
int* p{ nullptr };
*p = 10;
```

Comment: You don't write to where it points. You point it to where you wanna write!

Comment: It is an error to "write to nowhere".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dereferencing a nullptr is undefined behavior:

```
int* px = nullptr;
```

> Sometimes it is desirable to mark a pointer as invalid. This can be
>   achieved by the assignment of nullptr to the pointer. This pointer is
>   called a null pointer and dereferencing it results in undefined
>   behavior.

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/book/pointers

and that's exactly what's happening with

```
int* p{ nullptr };
*p = 10;
```

while in the first case **you're not writing to nowhere**, since the code

```
void InitPointer(int** pp)
{
    *pp = new int{ 10 };
}

int* p{ nullptr };
InitPointer(&p);
```

does initialize the pointer to a new integer of value 10. It roughly works this way:

```
int* p{ nullptr };

Address | Variable Name | Value
0x10      p               nullptr

InitPointer(&p);

Address | Variable Name | Value
0x10      p               nullptr
0x20      pp              0x10

*pp = new int{ 10 };

Address | Variable Name | Value
0x10      p               0x30
0x20      pp              0x10
0x30      -               10 (int)
```

and thus your p pointer now points to valid memory (which should later be freed).

Comment: Thank you, that helped. My mistake was that I thought that first pointer ***p** have address 0x00. Now I understand.

Answer (score 2):

There are **two** pointers in your example. The first one points nowhere, but the second one points to the first one. And using the pointer that points to pointer you set that pointer to point somewhere - sounds easy right? Maybe this will be better:

```
|---------|        |-------|
| nullptr | <----------X   |
|--- p----|        |--pp---|
```

So, `pp` is pointing to the "contents" of `p`. Using it, the function changes what `p` is pointing to:

```
|----|        |---------|        |-------|
| 10 | <-----------X    | <----------X   |
|----|        |----p----|        |--pp---|
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not writing to nowhere. You're passing `&p`, a pointer to `p`, into the function (hence the second `*`, indicating a pointer to a pointer), then dereferencing that pointer to write to `p` itself.

The second example doesn't have that extra level of indirection, and just tries to write to the nonexistent object that `p` points to, hence the error.